# Is there a way to sniff packets encrypted with WPA(2)?

Tags: wireless-networking, security, sniffing, wpa2-psk

I was reading about the recent FireSheep tool. People are saying that it is fine to sniff WPA/2 PSK networks because if you have the PSK, you can decrypt anyone's traffic.

I am wondering if there are any sniffers that actually decrypt and sniff in real time, that would actually allow that sort of attack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, probably the best known being [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/). It's free too!